# Wordpress Category Image in Categories response using Advanced Custom Fields returning null

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to add a category image field category image in categories response using Advanced Custom Field.

But the field is returning null, here is my code.

```
function addCategoryImage(){
    register_rest_field('category', 'categoryImage', array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'get_callback' => function() {
            $category = get_the_category();
            return get_field('category_image', 'category_' . $category_id);
        }

    ));
};

add_action('rest_api_init', 'addCategoryImage');
```

Comment: Please check `$category` is returning anything or not and this function is not inside loop so `get_the_category` will need post id to return category of particular post? How the `$category_id` is coming? I seems to be missing in your code, try `$cateogry->term_id`

Comment: $category returns empty array.

Comment: Then you must need to fix that first then you can get `category_image` from category

Answer (score 0):

The get_field('category_image', 'category_' . $category_id); function will not return anything if the category_id is null, so try to return $category and check if dose return anything or not, if it does, you still need to get the term_id if the post can have more than a category then you need to specify the term slug to get the id.

General advice: when dealing with API or internal function always print out all the variables you're using to check if they have any value in the first place. Don't write a full code and do the final test because f there is an issue it's going to be hard to find out where is the cause.

Check more details here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the exact answer I am looking for. The call back functions has these args.

```
    'get_callback' => function ( $object, $field_name, $request, $object_type ) {
    // ...
}
```

So I get the $object for each category from which I can get the term id. Here is the updated code.

```
function addCategoryImage(){
    register_rest_field('category', 'categoryImage', array(
        'get_callback' => function($cat) {
            return get_field('category_image', 'category_' . $cat['id']);
        }

    ));
};
add_action('rest_api_init', 'addCategoryImage');
```